# How to rename all files in one folder without extention name

Tags: matlab

I have one folder that has 160 dicom files without extension name such as (001, 002, 003....160). I want to add extension file (.dcm) into files by matlab. How to implement them by matlab code? Thank you. I am using Window OS and Matlab 7.0

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to rename *all* files in a folder, you can do it easily with a call to Windows from Matlab ([using `!`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_env/creating-opening-changing-and-deleting-files-and-folders.html#f0-38522)):

```
cd 'C:\Users\Luis\Desktop\tmp' %// change to desired folder
! ren * *.dcm
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have to implement it as MatLab code, I can think of this way of doing it using `movefile()`:

```
Files=dir();

for ii=1:lenght(Files)

    movefile(Files(ii).name,strcat(Files(ii).name,'.dpm'))

end
```

But @LuisMendo's solution is very good too.